# ggline stat_compare_means function messing up y axis scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been trying to plot something that looks like the last plot on this webpage in R (http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/76-add-p-values-and-significance-levels-to-ggplots/#stat_compare_means) with my ggline plot annotated with basic stats.

However, adding the stat_compare_means function to ggline compresses my y-axis scale to the maximum data point in my dataset so my mean line plot looks like a small line on the bottom of the graph. And if I shorten the scale using scale_y_continuous(limits=c(100, 125)) the statistics go away and the mean plot is out of proportion. How do I add the stats from the stat_compare_means function without changing the y-axis range in my plot?

Here is my code that gives me the compressed plot:

```
ggline(merge_sub_rmNA, x = "Quartiles", y = "LBXGLT", add = c("mean_se"), color = "RIAGENDR", palette = "jco", legend.title = "Gender")+ 
 stat_compare_means(method = "kruskal.test", label.y = 40)+ 
 stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "wilcox.test",
                 ref.group = ".all.", hide.ns = TRUE)
```

Here is the code that I tried to use to fix it, but it ends up removing the stats and making the error bars in the means plot incorrect.

```
ggline(merge_sub_rmNA, x = "Quartiles", y = "LBXGLT", add = c("mean_se"), color = "RIAGENDR", palette = "jco", legend.title = "Gender")+
 stat_compare_means(method = "kruskal.test", label.y = 40, inherit.aes = FALSE, mapping = aes(Quartiles, LBXGLT))+         
 scale_y_continuous(limits=c(100, 125))+
 stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "wilcox.test",
                 ref.group = ".all.", hide.ns = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, it was a simple addition of label.y and label.x to both stat_compare_means functions. You just need to make sure the numbers you place after label.y and label.x correspond to the x and y-axis values in your plot. For example, I put label.y = 120 because I want the stats to be added after 120 on the y-axis (rather than 600 which is what it was doing before).

Here is the code that works now:

```
ggline(merge_sub_rmNA, x = "Quartiles", y = "LBXGLT", add = c("mean_se"), color = "RIAGENDR", palette = "jco", legend.title = "Gender")+
 stat_compare_means(method = "kruskal.test", label.y = 120, label.x = 1)+      # Add global p-value
 stat_compare_means(label = "p.signif", method = "wilcox.test",
                 ref.group = ".all.", hide.ns = TRUE, label.y = 120)
```